# Do I need to use backend function for a custom Keras loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I would like to implement a custom loss function shown in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.06861.pdf) with **Keras**.

My loss is not going down and I have the feeling that it is because of the implementation of the loss: It doesn't use **Keras' backend** for everything but rather a combination of some `K` functions, simple operations and `numpy`:

```py
def l1_matrix_norm(M):
    return K.cast(K.max(K.sum(K.abs(M), axis=0)), 'float32')

def reconstruction_loss(patch_size, mask, center_weight=0.9):
    mask = mask.reshape(1, *mask.shape).astype('float32')
    mask_inv = 1 - mask

    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        diff = y_true - y_pred

        center_part = mask * diff
        center_part_normed = l1_matrix_norm(center_part)

        surr_part = mask_inv * diff
        surr_part_normed = l1_matrix_norm(surr_part)

        num_pixels = np.prod(patch_size).astype('float32')

        numerator = center_weight * center_part_normed + (1 - center_weight) * surr_part_normed

        return numerator / num_pixels

    return loss
```

Is it necessary to use Keras functions, if so for which type of operations do I need it (I saw some code where simple operations such as addition don't use `K`).

Also if I have to use a Keras backend function, can I instead use TensorFlows function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NN training depends on being able to compute the derivatives of all functions in the graph including the loss function. Keras backend functions and TensorFlow functions are annotated such that tensorflow (or other backend) automatically known how to compute gradients. That is not the case for numpy functions. It is possible to use non tf functions, if you do know how to compute their gradients manually (see `tf.custom_gradients`). In general, I would recommend with sticking with backend functions preferably and then tensorflow functions when necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out. does the final loss have to be a Keras.backend.constant?

Comment: No. I'm quite sure that the final result should not be a constant. A constant is a tensor that never changes in value. A loss function needs to return a tensor that is computed from the labels (aka. model.targets) and predictions.